# File removed but still being shown

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/) website. I have removed the `text-transform: uppercase;` from the code using WordPress backend but the front end still shows that the file has not been removed. Please guide.

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}
```

http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/

Comment: I know its a very silly question but I am facing this problem from more than a day.

Comment: clear browser cache?

Comment: The problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not remove it, instead change the above style to following

```
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

Make sure you're editing the right css, I mean you should be editing the following file. 
http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/wp-content/themes/chronicle/css/chronicle-menu.css?ver=4.2.4

Hope this helps you.!

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I was working with the wrong `chronical-menu.css` file. I went to the `css` folder and changed the right file.

Comment: Awesome..! Glad that it solved your issue.. Cheers.!

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the element it looks like `chronicle-menu.css` is still adding `text-transform:uppercase;`

[image: uppercase]

It sounds like you may have edited only the main `style.css` file or if you have edited `chronicle-menu.css` you have not saved your changes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There's still a `text-transform: uppercase` style defined on line 208 of the file http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/wp-content/themes/chronicle/css/chronicle-menu.css?ver=4.2.4

Using your browser's 'Inspect Element' tool is a great way to narrow down errors like this.